# Retrieving an element of an array that is a value of a hash with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I have the following hash:

```
hash = {"A" =>[1,2,3,4]}
```

Within that hash is a key `"A"` with the value of `[1,2,3,4]`.

Is there a possible way to access a single element within my array using the key-value pair?

Example (...yes I know this isn't legal Ruby):

```
hash["A",0] => 1
```

Or have the ability to see if the array included a value with the key-value pair?

```
hash["A".include? 4] => true
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you mean this?:

```
hash = {"A" =>[1,2,3,4]}
hash["A"][0] #=> 1
hash["A"].include? 4 #=> true
```

Comment: Thank you...I didn't know you could do that!

Comment: Well, `hash["A"]` will give you the value at key `"A"` in `hash` which is an array. That means you can use any array operations on `hash["A"]`.